# Decision variable declaration in concert technology (c++ and cplex)

Tags: c++, cplex

Hi i have a decion variable with 4D
X[i][j][k][l] and it's binary.How can i declare it please??
I am using concert technology c++ 2019 with cplex12.9. Is those two versions works togedher please?

Thank you

Comment: Please could you make your questions clearer? It seems as though you are asking two completely separate questions - how to declare a 4 dimensional decision variable and whether concert and cplex are compatible. Have you tried using them together?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> NumVarMatrix;
typedef IloArray<NumVarMatrix>   NumVar3Matrix;
...
file >> capacity >> fixedCost >> cost >> routes;
nbRoutes = routes.getSize();
/* define the num vars here for the 3-D matrix */
 NumVar3Matrix accept(env,nbClients);
 /* initialize this matrix */
 for(i=0; i< nbClients; i++) {
  accept[i] = NumVarMatrix(env, nbLocations);
for(j=0; j< nbLocations; j++) {
            accept[i][j] = IloNumVarArray(env, nbRoutes);
  for(k=0; k<nbRoutes; k++) {
   accept[i][j][k] = IloNumVar(env, 0.0, 1.0, ILOINT);
   }
  }
 }
```

from nice technote : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sample-create-and-use-multi-dimensional-ilonumvararray

NB:

With OPL CPLEX you could simply write

```
range i=1..2;
range j=1..3;
range k=1..4;
range l=1..5;

dvar boolean X[i][j][k][l];

subject to
{
  X[1][1][1][1]==1;
}
```